# Не получается считать строку из консоли

Tags: c++

Нужно считать строку из консоли в массив `char`.

Проблема в том что `scanf` и `cin` читают строку только до первого пробела, а мне нужно записать в массив строку целиком.

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Наверное, `cin`, а не `cout`.

Comment: Примеров же полно,  наберите -  c++ cin -  и вот оно счастье.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию-член класса входного потока `getline`.

Вот их объявления

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& getline(char_type* s, streamsize n);
basic_istream<charT,traits>& getline(char_type* s, streamsize n,
char_type delim);
```

Либо можете использовать функцию-член класса входного потока  `get`. Ее объявление выглядит похожим на предыдущую функцию.

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& get(char_type* s, streamsize n);
basic_istream<charT,traits>& get(char_type* s, streamsize n,
char_type delim);
```

Различие между этими функциями состоит в том, что первая функция считывает чимвол `delim` (если он не указан, то символ новой строки) из входного потока, но не заносит его в строку. В то время как вторая функция оставляет этот символ во входном потоке.

Думаю что вам лучше использовать первую функцию.

Вот пример работы с функцией `getline`

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 50;
    char s[N];

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline( s, N );

    std::cout << '\n' << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог работы с этой функцией может выглядеть, например, следующим образом:

```
Enter a sentence: Hello World!

Hello World!
```

Если вы перед вызовом этой функции осуществляли ввод с помощью оператора `operator >>`, то в буфере ввода может остаться символ новой строки. Его можно удалить вызовом другой функции-члена класса `ignore`  Простейший вызов этой функции выглядит как

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

Либо чтобы гарантированно убрать символ новой строки, то

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() );
```

Comment: Использую так:
'cin.getline(dirDirectory, 255);'
программа не дожидается пока я введу значение, а продолжает свою работу как-будто метода getline и нет. dirDirectory равен 0

Comment: @Rikipm Перед вызовом этой функции вызывается по крайней мере std::cin.ignore(); чтобы удалить символ новой строки, который остался в буфере скорей всего после вызова оператора operator >>.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь в решении этой задачи